# Quick solution check for the TSP

Tags: logic, computer-science, computational-complexity

Given a solution for the Boolean satisfiability or the Hamilton cycle problem it's obvious whether it's true or not, but how does one quickly check whether a solution for the TSP (travelling salesman problem) is true? That is, whether a given route is the shortest possible one. The problems are supposed to be equivalent...

Comment: A little tongue in cheek, but you could always convert it to a Boolean sat problem.

Comment: I would be a bit surprised if there were a certificate of optimality that was much less work (to create) than finding the optimum from the beginning. Does not seem the right kind of problem.

Comment: see http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2834/how-can-i-verify-a-solution-to-travelling-salesman-problem-in-polynomial-time  for example

Comment: @Jonny: What if the distances are irrational? How will one make them binary?

Comment: @DVD There isn't a standard way to represent irrational numbers.

Comment: @WillJagy: it's the modified decision problem, recalling this, it helps...

Comment: DVD, I don't know the different names for this; my feeling is that a proof of optimality somehow says that, given any two points in the current solution, the path from the first to the second is shorter than any other path using the same subset of vertices. To me, that seems a huge amount of work.

Comment: If the distances are irrational then the problem is either [Euclidean TSP](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/145652/Sum%20of%20Square%20Roots%20ToCT.pdf) or some other variation of the TSP. $\;$

Comment: @simonzack: Well, even if the numbers are square roots of natural numbers, the problem seems to require an analog computer. How does one convert them for the binary code?

Comment: "How does one convert them for" what "binary code?" $\:$  From the paper I linked to in my previous comment: "the best known result so far [ABKPM09](http://math-www.uni-paderborn.de/agpb/work/submitted.july.pdf) is containment in the counting hierarchy [CH](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:C#ch), which is a subclass of [PSPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPACE) ...". $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: Any binary code. How to discretize the problem?

Comment: @RickyDemer: It's not clear how stable the solution is to such a discretization. The papers seem highly specialized...

Comment: One can provably solve the problem with only a polynomial amount of memory by implementing $\hspace{.53 in}$ the algorithm that corresponds to the composition of [Proposition 1.1](http://math-www.uni-paderborn.de/agpb/work/submitted.july.pdf#page=2) and [Theorem 4.1](http://math-www.uni-paderborn.de/agpb/work/submitted.july.pdf#page=10). $\hspace{1.15 in}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23329/discussion-between-dvd-and-ricky-demer).

Comment: DVD's point about my now-deleted comment about discretization is very good; I don't see any reason why the discretization would preserve optimality forwards. $\:$ It's true that one "can discretize the problem by approximating the distances with rational numbers and then clearing denominators" (as I mentioned in that comment). $\:$ The lower bounds described in [these](http://cs.ou.edu/~qcheng/paper/ssrjournal.pdf) two [papers](http://www.cs.ou.edu/~qcheng/paper/lllssr.pdf) can be used to $\;\;\;$ (continued …) $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: (… continued) $\;\;\;$ determine "how accurate a discretization would have to be to guarantee that the discretization preserves optimality" backwards, and when those discretizations are sufficiently accurate, those algorithms can be used to find a positive integer $s$ such that the discretized lengths of non-optimal routes are greater than [the smallest discretized cost plus $s$] and the discretized lengths of optimal routes are less than [the smallest discretized cost plus $s$]. $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TSP has to be modified to a decision problem for it to be quickly checkable. Plus there is an issue of discretization for the Euclidean TSP.

A comment on the human performance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Human_performance_on_TSP

Answer (score 2):

One quickly checks "whether a solution for the TSP (travelling salesman problem) is true"

by quickly solving [a coNP-complete problem](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.3431v2.pdf).

I don't know how much asking about uniqueness changes the situation.

Comment: They assume integer disctances in the paper...

Comment: Not asking for the uniqueness...

Comment: A path can't be "the shortest possible one" if there are other paths of the same length. $\hspace{.9 in}$ (However, in that case, it could still be "a shortest possible one".) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Not sure about English grammar...

Comment: (I fixed the grammatical error in my previous comment.) $\;$